# Inverse problems with a discrete set of known parameters

Tags: inverse-problem

What are the techniques on inverse problems to discover the distribution of parameters from a discrete set of values? For instance, I know that my domain where the PDE is defined is made up of materials A, B and C, but I do not know how they are distributed inside the domain. Working with discrete optimization algorithms seems unfeasible. What are the techniques to solve such a problem?

Edit: I will describe the problem for just two materials, as it seems that the strategy is different than for multimaterials, according to Clason's comments (bang-bang vs multibang)

$$
\underset{u \in U}{\text{min}} \frac{1}{2} \lVert F(u) - y^{\delta} \rVert_Y \\
$$
where
$$
U = \{ u \in X : u \in \{ u_1, u_2 \} ~\text{pointwise}\}\\
F: X \rightarrow Y
$$
$X$ and $Y$ are function spaces and $y^{\delta} \in Y$

Comment: That's one question where I can't resist mentioning my own work, because that was exactly the motivation for it... [These slides](https://www.uni-due.de/~adf040p/talks/OCIP17_Clason.pdf) (hopefully) give a decent overview, and there's code on my [web page](https://www.uni-due.de/mathematik/agclason/clason_pub.php) (look for  papers involving "multibang").

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Is the problem much easier if there are two materials only? That's what it seems like from slide # 3.

Comment: Yes, the case of binary materials is well-known and in the classical control literature is called "bang-bang control" (hence the term "multibang" for more than two materials). In this case, you can just use the convex control constraints and don't need an additional penalty.

Comment: What do you mean by convex control constraint?

Comment: I mean the constraint $u_1 \leq u(x) \leq u_d$ (which defines a convex set, as opposed to $u(x)\in \{u_1,u_d\}$).

Comment: but that is not going to enforce solutions that are only $u_1$ or $u_d$ right? Why not adding a penalty term such as $\int (u-u_1)^2(u-u_d) ^2d\Omega$

Comment: Because that is non-convex, and hence not weakly lower semi-continuous, so you can't prove that a solution exist by standard techniques (and in fact, there are counter-examples). But while the constraints will not *enforce* such solutions (and neither will the multibang penalty), it turns out that in many cases you still obtain them. That's the price you pay for the efficient numerical solution (there ain't no free lunch...)

Comment: Could you point me to literature on this topic? Usually the bang-bang control literature does not treat inverse problems and it is difficult to follow. Just adding the penalty term that I mentioned above is challenging because the optimization algorithm quickly converges to a all $u_1$ or $u_2$ solution. Playing with the penalty term parameter is not helping.

Comment: As I said, your penalty is not well-posed, and you should see that in any sufficiently fine discretization. Regarding the counterexamples, the classical works are those by Murat and Tartar on homogenization problems. Also, we've just finished writing up our approach specifically for inverse problems, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01041 and https://github.com/clason/discreteregularization; maybe that helps. If not, you should edit your question to include the specific problem you're working on.

Comment: Just edited my question. I think I am having troubles understanding if the approach is very different for just two materials or more than two materials.